# edef and totcount

Tags: latex, counter, expansion

In the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{totcount}
\edef\name{}
\edef\create#1{\noexpand\newtotcounter{t#1}}
\def\setname#1{\edef\name{#1}}

\begin{document}
\setname{est} \create{\name}

\setname{estnew} \create{\name}

Total counts: \total{test}, \total{testnew}

\addtocounter{test}{10}
The test: \thetest

\addtocounter{testnew}{5}
The new test: \thetestnew
\end{document}
```

I want to create counters whose name is partially determined by my command `\name`. This works well, in that the counters are correctly created. However, `totcount` only works for `testnew` but not for `test`. In other words the output is:

```
Total counts: ??, 5
The test: 10
The new test: 5
```

Checking the aux file, it seems only `testnew` is set. In fact I have two identical lines of

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@testnew@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{testnew@totc}\fi\setcounter{testnew@totc}{5}
```

Clearly, there's a problem with my expansion, but I am unsure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104506/expanding-arguments-before-macro-call). I was under the impression that `edef` expands the arguments which is (now obviously) false. So the `\create` command has to defined a new command using `edef` so that the new command is expanded.

```
\edef\create#1{%
 \begingroup\edef\tmp{\endgroup\noexpand\newtotcounter{t#1}}
  \tmp}
```